# Is the sentence 'I've never known anyone as dishonest' correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> I've never known anyone **as** dishonest.

I am wondering if ***'as'*** is preposition or conjunction.

'dishonest' is  adjective, so I don't think it can be an preposition.

But even if 'as' is conjunction, I don't understand it exactly.

I think the meaning of the sentence would be 'I've never seen anyone dishonest like you.

But I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a adverb modifying the adjective "dishonest". It's typically used to form comparisons, but in your example, the second part of the comparison is missing. In full it might be something like "I've never known anyone as dishonest as you", where the first "as" is an adverb and the second a preposition.

Comment: I'm not up on contemporary grammar.  Would the second **as** in *as dishonest **as** you* and *as dishonest **as** you are*  be considered a preposition in both cases?

Comment: Yes, it would, at least in some modern grammars. The grammar is interesting since there is a difference in that in your first example "as" takes "you" as an immediate complement, a noun. In this analysis, _Ed is as dishonest as you_ will be syntactically like _Ed is similar to you_ where there is no question of _you_ being a clause. In your second example, the complement of "as" ("you are") is a reduced clause. Traditional grammar would analyse this "as" as conjunction, not a preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adverb *as* is used to make a comparison. In this case, it may be followed by an adjective, an adverb, or a word such as "much" or "many" + the preposition *as* + a noun, the object of comparison [(the source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as)).

> I've never known anyone as dishonest as he is.

The adverb *so*, which may be followed by an adjective or another adverb, is used for emphasizing a quality, feeling, or amount [(the source)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/so_1), i.e. as it should be used in the sentence:

> I've never known anyone so dishonest [from all dishonest people I happen to have known].

Comment: Note though that this sentence is taken out of context. In context, a phrase like "as he is" may be implied; i.e. there is a specific person that the speaker is comparing to for dishonesty